# HotSpot Virtual Machine error on Oracle Installation

Tags: installation, oracle11g

I am trying to Install Oracle 11G on Windows Xp 64 bit. The installer shows the progress bar for checking prerequisites and then crashes.

The log file is as below.
What can I do to solve the issue?

> #
>
> ## An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
>
> #
>
> ## EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000077d64e95,
>
> pid=3580, tid=2860
>   #
>
> ## Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (1.5.0_17-b04 mixed mode)
>
> ## Problematic frame:
>
> ## C  [kernel32.dll+0x24e95]
>
> #
>
> ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
>
> Current thread (0x0000000001ba0740): 
>   JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   [_thread_in_native, id=2860]
>
> siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005,
>   reading address 0x000000007f366f48
>
> Registers: EAX=0x0000000000000000,
>   EBX=0x000000007f366f48,
>   ECX=0xffffffffffffffff,
>   EDX=0x0000000000000104
>   ESP=0x000000000776de70,
>   EBP=0x0000000000000000,
>   ESI=0x00000000000004e4,
>   EDI=0x000000007f366f48
>   EIP=0x0000000077d64e95,
>   EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246
>
> Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000776de70)
>   0x000000000776de70:   0000000000000006
>   0000000000000000 0x000000000776de80:
>   0000000000000000 0000000000000020
>   0x000000000776de90:   0000000000000005
>   00000000001956b0 0x000000000776dea0:
>   0000000010020200 00000000080b95e6
>   0x000000000776deb0:   0000000020a9c058
>   0000000077efb1e9 0x000000000776dec0:
>   0000000000000000 0000000077c4ef3d
>   0x000000000776ded0:   0000ebe94f6aad20
>   0000000001ba0740 0x000000000776dee0:
>   000000000776e388 000000001257ad50
>   0x000000000776def0:   0000000001e9cba1
>   0000000020a9c340 0x000000000776df00:
>   000000000000006d 000000000776e348
>   0x000000000776df10:   000000001257ad50
>   0000000006cbd5f9 0x000000000776df20:
>   000000000776dfe8 000000000776e0a8
>   0x000000000776df30:   0000000000000000
>   000007ff7f1e4273 0x000000000776df40:
>   000000000776e080 0000000000000104
>   0x000000000776df50:   0000ebe94f6aad20
>   00000000001956b0 0x000000000776df60:
>   000000000016a090 000000000776dfe8
>
> Instructions: (pc=0x0000000077d64e95)
>   0x0000000077d64e85:   ff 33 c0 48 b9
>   ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 48 8b fb
>   0x0000000077d64e95:   f2 ae 48 f7 d1
>   44 8b e9 e9 1e 86 00 00 90 90 90
>
> Stack:
>   [0x0000000007670000,0x0000000007770000),
>   sp=0x000000000776de70,  free
>   space=1015k Native frames: (J=compiled
>   Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code,
>   C=native code) C 
>   [kernel32.dll+0x24e95]
>
> [error occurred during error
>   reporting, step 120, id 0xc0000005]
>
> Java frames: (J=compiled Java code,
>   j=interpreted, Vv=VM code) j 
>   sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getLinkLocation(JJZ)J+0
>   j 
>   sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getLinkLocation(Z)Lsun/awt/shell/ShellFolder;+20
>   j 
>   sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.isDirectory()Z+69
>   j 
>   sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.isDirectory()Z+79
>   j 
>   sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;+156
>   j 
>   sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;+4
>   j 
>   oracle.bali.ewt.olaf2.OracleFileChooserUI.installComponents(Ljavax/swing/JFileChooser;)V+794
>   j 
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI.installUI(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)V+47
>   j 
>   oracle.bali.ewt.olaf2.OracleFileChooserUI.installUI(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)V+2
>   j 
>   javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(Ljavax/swing/plaf/ComponentUI;)V+42
>   j 
>   javax.swing.JFileChooser.updateUI()V+40
>   j 
>   javax.swing.JFileChooser.setup(Ljavax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView;)V+73
>   j 
>   javax.swing.JFileChooser.(Ljava/io/File;Ljavax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView;)V+133
>   j 
>   javax.swing.JFileChooser.()V+9 j
>   oracle.install.commons.swing.XmlBeanStoreFileChooser.()V+1
>   j 
>   oracle.install.commons.base.summary.SummaryPane.buildUI()V+25
>   j 
>   oracle.install.commons.base.summary.SummaryPane.()V+35
>   j 
>   oracle.install.commons.base.interview.common.view.SummaryGUI.()V+9
>   v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub j 
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
>   j 
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+72
>   j 
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5
>   j 
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+92
>   j 
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance0()Ljava/lang/Object;+118
>   j 
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance()Ljava/lang/Object;+15
>   j 
>   oracle.install.commons.flow.ViewManager.getView(Ljava/lang/String;)Loracle/install/commons/flow/View;+72
>   j 
>   oracle.install.commons.flow.State.getView()Loracle/install/commons/flow/View;+19
>   j 
>   oracle.install.commons.flow.AbstractFlowExecutor.loadView(Loracle/install/commons/util/Graph;)V+20
>   j 
>   oracle.install.commons.flow.AbstractGraphicalFlowExecutor.access$001(Loracle/install/commons/flow/AbstractGraphicalFlowExecutor;Loracle/install/commons/util/Graph;)V+2
>   j 
>   oracle.install.commons.flow.AbstractGraphicalFlowExecutor$1.call()Ljava/lang/Void;+8
>   j 
>   oracle.install.commons.flow.AbstractGraphicalFlowExecutor$1.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
>   j 
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun()V+22
>   j 
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+4
>   j 
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch()V+47
>   j 
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+26
>   j 
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Component;)Z+233
>   j 
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+26
>   j 
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
>   j 
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
>   j 
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
>   v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
>
> ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------
>
> Java Threads: ( => current thread )
>   0x0000000001ba0490 JavaThread "Image
>   Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked,
>   id=3088]   0x0000000001ba1cc0
>   JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=3252]
>   0x0000000001ba1a10 JavaThread
>   "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_blocked,
>   id=4912]   0x0000000001b9e700
>   JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM"
>   [_thread_blocked, id=3504]
>   0x0000000001ba1760 JavaThread "Worker
>   3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3660]
>   0x0000000001ba14b0 JavaThread "Worker
>   2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3720]
>   0x0000000001ba1200 JavaThread "Worker
>   1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1936]
>   0x0000000001ba0f50 JavaThread "Worker
>   0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4016]
>   =>0x0000000001ba0740 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native,
>   id=2860]   0x0000000001b9f720
>   JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown"
>   [_thread_blocked, id=2276]
>   0x0000000001b9ff30 JavaThread "Java2D
>   Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked,
>   id=4064]   0x0000000001b9f9d0
>   JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon
>   [_thread_in_native, id=2376]
>   0x0000000001b9f1c0 JavaThread "Low
>   Memory Detector" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=1764]
>   0x000000000557f720 JavaThread
>   "CompilerThread1" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=4204]
>   0x000000000557f450 JavaThread
>   "CompilerThread0" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=3604]
>   0x000000000557f180 JavaThread
>   "AdapterThread" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=1976]
>   0x0000000001b9ef10 JavaThread "Signal
>   Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked,
>   id=2296]   0x0000000001b9ec60
>   JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=3608]
>   0x0000000001b9e9b0 JavaThread
>   "Reference Handler" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=2012]
>
> Other Threads:   0x0000000001b8d980
>   VMThread [id=4856]
>   0x0000000001b8daa0 WatcherThread
>   [id=1224]
>
> VM state:not at safepoint (normal
>   execution)
>
> VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a
>   thread: None
>
> Heap  PSYoungGen      total 62592K,
>   used 56702K [0x000000001d410000,
>   0x0000000021410000,
>   0x0000000021410000)   eden space
>   59648K, 93% used
>   [0x000000001d410000,0x0000000020aab7d8,0x0000000020e50000)
>   from space 2944K, 26% used
>   [0x0000000020e50000,0x0000000020f140c0,0x0000000021130000)
>   to   space 2880K, 0% used
>   [0x0000000021140000,0x0000000021140000,0x0000000021410000)
>   PSOldGen        total 12800K, used
>   9744K [0x0000000015410000,
>   0x0000000016090000,
>   0x000000001d410000)   object space
>   12800K, 76% used
>   [0x0000000015410000,0x0000000015d94300,0x0000000016090000)
>   PSPermGen       total 54016K, used
>   38334K [0x0000000010010000,
>   0x00000000134d0000,
>   0x0000000015410000)   object space
>   54016K, 70% used
>   [0x0000000010010000,0x000000001257f820,0x00000000134d0000)
>
> Dynamic libraries: 0x0000000000400000
>   - 0x0000000000412000  C:\DOCUME~1\rrscw\LOCALS~1\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe
>   0x0000000077ec0000 -
>   0x0000000077ff9000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
>   0x0000000077d40000 -
>   0x0000000077eb3000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
>   0x000007ff7fee0000 -
>   0x000007ff7ffe5000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
>   0x000007ff7fd30000 -
>   0x000007ff7fec9000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
>   0x000007ff7e9c0000 -
>   0x000007ff7e9e2000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
>   0x0000000077c20000 -
>   0x0000000077d2c000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
>   0x000007ff7fc90000 -
>   0x000007ff7fd2b000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
>   0x000007ff7fc00000 -
>   0x000007ff7fc86000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
>   0x0000000180000000 -
>   0x00000001800f3000
>     c:\progra~1\quickh~1\quickh~2\wl_hoo~1.dll
>   0x000007ff7f190000 -
>   0x000007ff7fb9a000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
>   0x000007ff7ef60000 -
>   0x000007ff7effb000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
>   0x000007ff7f000000 -
>   0x000007ff7f187000
>     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.3790.3959_x-ww_0A7B2435\comctl32.dll 0x0000000008000000 -
>   0x0000000008561000
>     C:\DOCUME~1\rrscw\LOCALS~1\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\jdk\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll 0x000007ff7e240000 -
>   0x000007ff7e290000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
>   0x0000000010000000 -
>   0x000000001000b000
>     C:\DOCUME~1\rrscw\LOCALS~1\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\jdk\jre\bin\hpi.dll
>   0x000007ff7e380000 -
>   0x000007ff7e390000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
>   0x00000000003d0000 -
>   0x00000000003e1000
>     C:\DOCUME~1\rrscw\LOCALS~1\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\jdk\jre\bin\verify.dll
>   0x0000000001e40000 -
>   0x0000000001e6c000
>     C:\DOCUME~1\rrscw\LOCALS~1\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\jdk\jre\bin\java.dll 0x0000000001e70000 -
>   0x0000000001e86000
>     C:\DOCUME~1\rrscw\LOCALS~1\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\jdk\jre\bin\zip.dll
>   0x0000000006b50000 -
>   0x0000000006d6b000    C:\Documents and
>   Settings\rrscw\Local
>   Settings\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\jdk\jre\bin\awt.dll
>   0x000007ff78f10000 -
>   0x000007ff78f51000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
>   0x000007ff7d500000 -
>   0x000007ff7d539000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.dll
>   0x000007ff57140000 -
>   0x000007ff573c5000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
>   0x000007ff77230000 -
>   0x000007ff772af000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
>   0x000007ff79190000 -
>   0x000007ff79202000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ddraw.dll
>   0x000007ff793e0000 -
>   0x000007ff793e8000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
>   0x000007ff7a410000 -
>   0x000007ff7a4af000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
>   0x0000000007430000 -
>   0x00000000074aa000    C:\Documents and
>   Settings\rrscw\Local
>   Settings\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\jdk\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
>   0x00000000075b0000 -
>   0x00000000075cb000    C:\Documents and
>   Settings\rrscw\Local
>   Settings\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\jdk\jre\bin\net.dll
>   0x000007ff77310000 -
>   0x000007ff77340000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
>   0x000007ff77140000 -
>   0x000007ff7714c000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
>   0x0000000007650000 -
>   0x000000000765c000    C:\Documents and
>   Settings\rrscw\Local
>   Settings\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\jdk\jre\bin\nio.dll
>   0x0000000007770000 -
>   0x00000000077ad000    C:\Documents and
>   Settings\rrscw\Local
>   Settings\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\oui\lib\win64\oraInstaller.dll
>   0x000007ff7fbf0000 -
>   0x000007ff7fbfb000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
>   0x0000000078000000 -
>   0x0000000078060000    C:\Documents and
>   Settings\rrscw\Local
>   Settings\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\oui\lib\win64\msvcrt.dll
>   0x000007ff771b0000 -
>   0x000007ff7722d000
>     C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll
>   0x000007ff7e8f0000 -
>   0x000007ff7e93e000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
>   0x000007ff7e9f0000 -
>   0x000007ff7e9fb000
>     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
>   0x000007ff7e950000 -
>   0x000007ff7e9b6000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
>   0x000007ff7ea00000 -
>   0x000007ff7ea07000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
>   0x000007ff57040000 -
>   0x000007ff57071000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\iphlpapi.dll
>   0x000007ff7e560000 -
>   0x000007ff7e58b000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MPRAPI.dll
>   0x000007ff7e780000 -
>   0x000007ff7e7db000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ACTIVEDS.dll
>   0x000007ff7e730000 -
>   0x000007ff7e770000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\adsldpc.dll
>   0x000007ff77370000 -
>   0x000007ff77409000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NETAPI32.dll
>   0x000007ff7e3a0000 -
>   0x000007ff7e3d9000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\credui.dll
>   0x000007ff7e040000 -
>   0x000007ff7e05c000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ATL.DLL
>   0x000007ff7ebc0000 -
>   0x000007ff7ecd6000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
>   0x000007ff7e610000 -
>   0x000007ff7e625000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rtutils.dll
>   0x000007ff77150000 -
>   0x000007ff77166000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SAMLIB.dll
>   0x000007ff7dac0000 -
>   0x000007ff7dc38000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
>   0x000007ff6d200000 -
>   0x000007ff6d293000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
>   0x000007ff77170000 -
>   0x000007ff7717b000
>     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
>   0x0000000007970000 -
>   0x0000000007977000    C:\Documents and
>   Settings\rrscw\Local
>   Settings\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\oui\lib\win64\orauts.dll
>   0x0000000007b20000 -
>   0x0000000007b2d000    C:\Documents and
>   Settings\rrscw\Local
>   Settings\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\oui\lib\win64\orawsec11.dll
>   0x0000000078130000 -
>   0x00000000781f9000
>     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4027_x-ww_189D5EB0\MSVCR80.dll 0x0000000007c50000 -
>   0x0000000007cf4000    C:\Documents and
>   Settings\rrscw\Local
>   Settings\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\oui\lib\win64\orasrvm11.dll
>   0x0000000007a90000 -
>   0x0000000007abd000    C:\Documents and
>   Settings\rrscw\Local
>   Settings\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\jdk\jre\bin\dcpr.dll 0x000007ff76200000 -
>   0x000007ff762ef000
>     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.3790.3959_x-ww_AB06DEB0\comctl32.dll 0x000007ff772d0000 -
>   0x000007ff772f1000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MPR.dll
>   0x000007ff7ccc0000 -
>   0x000007ff7ccca000
>     C:\WINDOWS\System32\drprov.dll
>   0x000007ff649f0000 -
>   0x000007ff64a06000
>     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ntlanman.dll
>   0x000007ff65140000 -
>   0x000007ff65164000
>     C:\WINDOWS\System32\NETUI0.dll
>   0x000007ff650e0000 -
>   0x000007ff65138000
>     C:\WINDOWS\System32\NETUI1.dll
>   0x000007ff7ceb0000 -
>   0x000007ff7cebd000
>     C:\WINDOWS\System32\davclnt.dll
>   0x000007ff7ce50000 -
>   0x000007ff7ce91000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\apphelp.dll
>   0x000007ff7ea10000 -
>   0x000007ff7eaee000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
>   0x000007ff7eaf0000 -
>   0x000007ff7ebb6000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMRes.dll
>   0x000007ff7df70000 -
>   0x000007ff7df7c000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\LINKINFO.dll
>   0x000007ff7df80000 -
>   0x000007ff7dfb1000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntshrui.dll
>
> VM Arguments: jvm_args:
>   -Doracle.installer.library_loc=C:\DOCUME~1\rrscw\LOCALS~1\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\oui\lib\win64
>   -Doracle.installer.oui_loc=C:\DOCUME~1\rrscw\LOCALS~1\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\oui
>   -Doracle.installer.bootstrap=TRUE -Doracle.installer.startup_location=I:\Setups\Oracle\database\install
>   -Doracle.installer.jre_loc=C:\DOCUME~1\rrscw\LOCALS~1\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM\jdk/jre
>   -Doracle.installer.exec_location=I:\Setups\Oracle\database\install\oui.exe
>   -Doracle.installer.nlsEnabled=TRUE -Doracle.installer.prereqConfigLoc= -Xmx192m java_command: oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller
>   -scratchPath C:\DOCUME~1\rrscw\LOCALS~1\Temp\OraInstall2011-03-30_10-02-25AM
>   -sourceLoc I:\Setups\Oracle\database\install../stage/products.xml
>   -sourceType network -timestamp 2011-03-30_10-02-25AM Launcher Type:
>   SUN_STANDARD
>
> Environment Variables:
>   PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio
>   Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Roxio
>   Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\R\R-2.12.2\library\rscproxy\libs\i386;C:\Program
>   Files\R\R-2.12.2\bin\i386;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\
>   USERNAME=rrscw OS=Windows_NT
>   PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=EM64T Family 6
>   Model 26 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
>
> ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------
>
> OS: Windows XP 64bit Build 3790
>   Service Pack 2
>
> CPU:total 4 em64t ht
>
> Memory: 4k page, physical
>   6273948k(4849464k free), swap
>   7972228k(7161264k free)
>
> vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM (1.5.0_17-b04) for
>   windows-amd64, built on Nov 10 2008
>   01:04:27 by "java_re" with unknown MS
>   VC++:1400

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after some searching found [this solution](https://www.oliver-matuschin.de/en/blog/oracle-installation-hiccups) which has you **remove all shortcuts from your Windows Desktop**. Apparently the installer chokes on these for some reason. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I had the same issue, I found it was related to my Google Drive shortcuts. I removed them and all was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle sometimes has problems installing from a directory with a space in it.